# InAppBilling pricing list without ProductID's

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-pay, android-billing

Am working on a Android Application where contents has to be sold within the Application(native), I has found InAppBilling Api serves the purpose, but within InAppBilling pricing configuration we may have to configure the individual id's for all items which we are selling, its unable to maintain the product id's, as often the items will be added/removed, reason is we have 50k items, so we have to edit the Developer console listing as well. 
Then checked with Android-Pay, as per the terms digital contents cannot be sold via Pay, need some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Later found the solution as per the google docs,
for selling digital content, Google recommends - InAppBilling 
for selling physical goods, Google recommends - Android Pay